# Unhandled exception error

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2008, memory-management, out-of-memory, cplex

I call cplex to solve an optimization problem in visual studio.
My problem is as simple as this:

```
IloNumVarArray a(env,N,0,IloInfinity);
IloNumVarArray d(env,N,0,IloInfinity);

IloModel Model(env);    
//objective function
IloExpr obj(env);
for(IloInt n=0; n<N;n++)
  obj+=a[n]*c1[n]-d[n]*c2[n];
Model.add(IloMinimize(env,obj));
obj.end();

for(IloInt n=0;n<N;n++){
    Model.add(a[n]==0);
    Model.add(d[n]==0);
}
IloCplex cplex_p(Model);
cplex_p.setParam(IloCplex::EpGap,0.0001);
cplex_p.solve(); 
cplex_p.end();
Model.end();
```

But each time it gives me this error message:

```
Unhandled exception at 0x74eeb9bc in For-Calling-Cplex.exe: Microsoft C++ exception: IloWrongUsage at memory location 0x0027fbe4..
```

What have I done wrong?

Comment: Why do you think it's a memory-related issue? From the data included in the question, it doesn't appear to be such.

Comment: what are c1 and c2 in your code?

Comment: parameters `IloNumArray c_base(env, N);`
  ` IloNumArray c_extra(env, N);`

Answer (score 1):

According to the C++ rules, if a program throws an exception which is not caught, the program is immediately terminated (via `std::terminate()`). In this case we can see that the runtime prints the name of the exception (`IloWrongUsage`) upon termination.

In order to get more details about the cause of the problem, you should wrap your code in an exception handler and examine the information the exception carries with it.

For example:

```
int main(int, char*[])
{
    try
    {
        // your code goes here
    }
    catch ( IloException& e )
    {
        // based on the ILOG CPLEX 10.0 User’s Manual / Languages and APIs / Handling Errors
        std::cout << e << std::endl;
        e.end();
    }
    catch ( ... )
    {
        std::cout << "Unknown exception\n";
    }
}
```

After that, you will (probably) see the details of the exception. Googling shows that `IloWrongUsage` means that some parameters are wrong or something like that (I have no idea what cplex is).

**UPD** I found a CPLEX manual in the Net, and it appears to imply that `IloException` does not inherit `std::exception` (which is not a good practice, generally speaking). So I've edited my example according to the manual.

Comment: Throwing an exception that isn't handled results in a call to `std::terminate()`. Nothing undefined about it (although it's implementation-defined whether the stack is unwound). Agreed, though, that a try/catch clause in main is usually a good idea.

Comment: try and catch didn't solved my issue! what I think is that there is a problem with my variables `a` and `d`. I even first assigned 0 to them and then introduced the constraints. but as soon as reading a line where the variables are in it gives the error

Comment: @Anna you should put a try/catch (IloException) around the entire function and print the exception.

Comment: @Pete You're right, I'll fix my answer. Damn, my memory fails me more often than it's used to.

Comment: @Anna As David says, you should print the exception details (or maybe examine them with a debugger) to get the information about the actual error. I've edited my answer a bit, adding some CPLEX-specific code to the example.

Answer (score 1):

The use of the end function is premature.

```
obj.end();
```

Since you added it to the model as an objective function.  You shouldn't really call the .end() functions unless you are making iteratively creating models and are running out of memory.

If you are using msvc, you should compile in debug mode and [set a breakpoint](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4558436/break-on-exception-throw-setting-the-default) to make the debugger stop when the exception is actually thrown.
Next, you should always catch IloException at a high level.  Write your function call in a try/catch block

```
try {
   buildModel():
} catch (const IloException& e)
{
   cerr << e;
   throw; // if you like
}
```

Comment: 1- Yes it iteratively creating models. 2- your comment about `==` was my typo.